# Does MongoDb use new space on update.. considering a text field is using more space after update?

Tags: mongodb

let's do an update on mongoDb.
Current data is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946347db27ca99e20a95f"), "name" : "abc"}`
```

Now comes an update:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946347db27ca99e20a95f"), "name" : "abcdefgh"}
```

1. Obviously, there is no space for the name field. What does MongoDb do in update? Garbage collect old space and make new entry? Or does it deal with blocks like relational database, and create new block and chains it with existing? (this q is important)
2. What does it do with indexes in case the "name" field is indexed? (Update the indexes as expected) Thx

Comment: MongoDB uses WiredTiger Storage Engine. You should find an answer in [WiredTiger Overview and Features](https://source.wiredtiger.com/mongodb-5.0/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts

1. What happens at the disc storage level on the update?
2. What happens to indexes if an indexed field is updated?

Let me answer the second part (I've no clue about the first one). On every update, mongo will adjust its index. That means it will re-adjust the keys of the target collection. For example, say you had a very simple document structure like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("SOME_RANDOM_OID"),
    name: 'John Doe',
    gender: female
}
```

and assume you have documents containing genders male/female only. This means your index will only have two keys.
And now, if you update the above document like below:

```
{
        _id: ObjectId("SOME_RANDOM_OID"),
        name: 'John Doe',
        gender: male
}
```

Mongo will pull the _id of the above document (that is *ObjectId("SOME_RANDOM_OID")* ) from the female key and put it into the male key of its index B-Tree.
[Mongo doc reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-performance/#indexes)